# Error building webpage: RStudio + blogdown + Ezhil Theme

Tags: r, hugo, blogdown

I am new to blogdown/hugo themes and want to build a webpage using the [Ezhil](https://themes.gohugo.io/ezhil/) theme with RStudio. I am following the instructions of [blogdown](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/a-quick-example.html).

In particular, after [creating the project on RStudio](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/a-quick-example.html#create-project), I am not able to build/serve the site. If I run `serve_site()`, I obtain

```
> blogdown::serve_site()
Launching the server via the command:
  /Users/brunoconteleite/Library/Application Support/Hugo/0.84.2/hugo server --bind 127.0.0.1 -p 4321 --themesDir themes -t ezhil -D -F --navigateToChanged
Error: Error building site: logged 1 error(s)
```

Instead, if I run `hugo_build()`, I obtain

```
> blogdown::hugo_build()
Start building sites … 
hugo v0.84.2-E0C67958+extended darwin/amd64 BuildDate=2021-06-28T10:59:21Z VendorInfo=gohugoio
ERROR 2021/06/29 13:20:37 instagram shortcode: Missing config value for services.instagram.accessToken. This can be set in config.toml, but it is recommended to configure this via the HUGO_SERVICES_INSTAGRAM_ACCESSTOKEN OS environment variable. If you are using a Client Access Token, remember that you must combine it with your App ID using a pipe symbol (<APPID>|<CLIENTTOKEN>) otherwise the request will fail.
If you feel that this should not be logged as an ERROR, you can ignore it by adding this to your site config:
ignoreErrors = ["error-missing-instagram-accesstoken"]
Total in 40 ms
Error: Error building site: logged 1 error(s)
```

I tried to add the suggested `ignoreErrors = ["error-missing-instagram-accesstoken"]` line of code to the `config.yalm` file but could not address this issue.

Comment: Typo: `config.yalm` to `config.yaml` on the last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to turn the `TOML` code into `YAML` if your `config` file has `yaml` or `yml` extension.

So, rather than `ignoreErrors = ["error-missing-instagram-accesstoken"]`, add `ignoreErrors: "error-missing-instagram-accesstoken"` line to your `config.yaml` file. It should work.